# GIT: Should I clone a repository or download it as zip?

Tags: git, github, atlassian-sourcetree

I am using Source Tree as a GIT Client. I have been trying to fork an open source repository. I tried the clone the repository and it is taking ages to clone. I have a 4g internet connection and the speed is also high. My question is should I clone the repository or there is an option in Github to download as .zip.
Would there be any difference in it? In terms of speed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're intended to contribute to this repo, then you should clone it. Without cloning you're not able to push changes. It will take longer because you must download whole diff history (many git objects). As bigger projects is as longer it would take, but only once (later you download only newer commits).

If you only want to deploy something, you can download zip file.